# From Selenium To Requests

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

I am trying to learn how to use the requests module so i dont need to be scraping with Selenium.

This is the code i have so far, that prints a table from a webpage.

I cant figure out how i could use requests to make this code faster and in a pythonic way.

```
#my imports
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException,StaleElementReferenceException
from datetime import datetime
import untangle,xmltodict,glob, os, csv, time
from openpyxl import load_workbook

#Paths that i use later in code
path = r"G:\Meu Drive\Balanços\\"
pathxml =r"C:\Users\GuilhermeMachado\Documents\XML\\"

#Pandas table configs
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

#chromedriver options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--incognito")
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory": pathxml,
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
  "download.directory_upgrade": True,
  "safebrowsing.enabled": True
})

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(2)

#URL i want to get data from
driver.get('http://www.b3.com.br/pt_br/produtos-e-servicos/negociacao/renda-variavel/fundos-de-investimentos/fii/')
#driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)
iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'bvmf_iframe')))
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

#the table i need to scrape
tabel = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//table[@class="responsive"]')))

time.sleep(2)
df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[0]
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use requests, you won't get the data in the iframe. Which is what you seem to be looking for. When looking at your page, I can see the iframe table is referenced by the following URL http://bvmf.bmfbovespa.com.br/Fundos-Listados/FundosListados.aspx?tipoFundo=imobiliario&Idioma=pt-br

If that url remains constant, then you can use requests to get the content of that url using the following. Then you can use beautifulSoup to parse the table.

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen    
page = Request("http://bvmf.bmfbovespa.com.br/Fundos-Listados/FundosListados.aspx?tipoFundo=imobiliario&amp;Idioma=pt-br")
content = urlopen(page).read()
print(content)
```

Edit: Alternatively, you can still request the main page. Use beautifulsoup to find the iframe and get the src tag which would result in that new link. Then use another request to get the table data.

Edit2: Simple solution

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = Request("http://www.b3.com.br/pt_br/produtos-e-servicos/negociacao/renda-variavel/fundos-de-investimentos/fii/")
content = urlopen(page).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
iframe_url = soup.find('iframe', id='bvmf_iframe')['src']

page = Request(iframe_url)
content = urlopen(page).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table')
print(table)
```

Comment: What would the bs4 code be like? I am just used to use selenium, but will learn bs4 with your answer and other searches.

Comment: I added a basic solution. The table data will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of getting the table data using [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/) and [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).
Note that neither is part of standard library and they need to be installed (with pip, for example).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://bvmf.bmfbovespa.com.br/Fundos-Listados/FundosListados.aspx?tipoFundo=imobiliario&Idioma=pt-br'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

table = soup.find('table')
rows = table.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    columns = row.find_all('td')
    if len(columns) == 4:  # skip rows without 4 cells
        razao, fundo, segmento, codigo = columns
        print(razao.text)  # prints the company names
```

Comment: I liked you answer because it brings me organized in columns, but i would need to click each company and add to the table the 'CNPJ' numbers on each company Page. Is this suitable for the code?

Comment: You can extract the company link from the table cell like this: `razao_url = razao.find('a')['href']`. Then you can visit that link and extract the CNPJ number (using BeautifulSoup).