# Shifting pythone code written in selenium to scrapy or requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I have return code in selenium. It works fine. It scraps the portal and extracts the data in table. But now I am trying to shift either to scrapy or requests.
I tried learning both and failed misserably. The selenium structure is fit in my mind. It will take me long to understand basics of requests or scrappy and then use them. The shortcut is to get some tips on how to do it directly in connection with present code.

Why am I shifting? -
I posted the code to seek suggestions for refactoring the code ([here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/245075/201050)). Two of the comments have suggested me to shift to requests. That has triggered the effort. Then after some primary search I realized, I can avoid selenium and requests or scrappy can save huge time for me.

I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61193148/3604513). But that dose not solve my issue.

Can someone help with this? Thanks in advance.

The code (including URL) -

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, \
    TimeoutException, StaleElementReferenceException, WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from FIR_logging import logger
import os
import time
import pandas as pd


# base function

def get_url(some_url):
    while True:
        try:
            driver.get(some_url)
            break
        except WebDriverException:
            time.sleep(60)
            continue
    driver.refresh()



# Some constants:

URL = r'https://www.mhpolice.maharashtra.gov.in/Citizen/MH/PublishedFIRs.aspx'
options = FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--private-window")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
get_url(URL)
time.sleep(10)

Download_Directory = r'/some_directory/raw_footage7'

COLUMNS = ['Sr.No.', 'State', 'District', 'Police Station', 'Year', 'FIR No.', 'Registration Date', 'FIR No',
           'Sections']

ALL_Districts = ['AKOLA', 'AMRAVATI CITY', 'AMRAVATI RURAL', 'AURANGABAD CITY',
                 'AURANGABAD RURAL', 'BEED', 'BHANDARA', 'BRIHAN MUMBAI CITY', 'BULDHANA',
                 'CHANDRAPUR', 'DHULE', 'GADCHIROLI', 'GONDIA', 'HINGOLI', 'JALGAON', 'JALNA',
                 'KOLHAPUR', 'LATUR', 'NAGPUR CITY', 'NAGPUR RURAL', 'NANDED', 'NANDURBAR',
                 'NASHIK CITY', 'NASHIK RURAL', 'NAVI MUMBAI', 'OSMANABAD', 'PALGHAR', 'PARBHANI',
                 'PIMPRI-CHINCHWAD', 'PUNE CITY', 'PUNE RURAL', 'RAIGAD', 'RAILWAY AURANGABAD',
                 'RAILWAY MUMBAI', 'RAILWAY NAGPUR', 'RAILWAY PUNE', 'RATNAGIRI', 'SANGLI', 'SATARA',
                 'SINDHUDURG', 'SOLAPUR CITY', 'SOLAPUR RURAL', 'THANE CITY', 'THANE RURAL', 'WARDHA',
                 'WASHIM', 'YAVATMAL']


# other functions


def district_selection(name):
    dist_list = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
        "#ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlDistrict"))
    dist_list_options = dist_list.options
    names = [o.get_attribute("text")
             for o in dist_list.options if o.get_attribute("text") not in (
                 'Select')]
    if name not in names:
        logger.info(f"{name} is not in list")
        return False
    dist_list.select_by_visible_text(name)
    time.sleep(8)


def enter_date(date):
    # enters start as well as end dates with "action chains."
    WebDriverWait(driver, 160).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                        '#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDateOfRegistrationFrom')))
    from_date_field = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
        '#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDateOfRegistrationFrom')

    to_date_field = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
        '#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDateOfRegistrationTo')

    ActionChains(driver).click(from_date_field).send_keys(
        date).move_to_element(to_date_field).click().send_keys(
        date).perform()

    logger.info(f'date entered: {date}')


def search():
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSearch').click()


def number_of_records():
    """captures the text indicating number of records.
    converts it to integer. if 0 returns and appends name of district to the list
    if page is not loaded. it tries one more time for 15 secs."""
    time_counter = 1
    while time_counter < 19:
        try:
            records_number = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
                '#ContentPlaceHolder1_lbltotalrecord').text
            if records_number == '':
                time.sleep(1)
                continue
            else:
                records_number = int(records_number)
            if records_number != 0:
                logger.info(f"{district}: {records_number}")

                return records_number
            else:
                logger.info(f"no records @ {district}")
                return False
        except (NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException, StaleElementReferenceException):
            logger.info("page is not loaded")
            time_counter += 1
            continue


def extract_table_current(name, single):
    # entire table of record to be taken to the list.
    soup = BS(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    main_table = soup.find("table", {"id": "ContentPlaceHolder1_gdvDeadBody"})
    time_counter = 1
    while main_table is None:
        if time_counter < 16:
            logger.info(f"the table did not load @ {name}")
            time_counter += 1
        else:
            logger.info(f"the table did not load @ {name}."
                        f"stopped trying")
            return
    links_for_pages = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.gridPager a')
    rows = main_table.find_all("tr")
    if links_for_pages is None:

        for row in rows:
            time.sleep(8)
            if '...' not in row.text:
                cells = row.find_all('td')
                cells = cells[0:9]  # drop the last column
                # store data in list
                single.append([cell.text for cell in cells])
    else:
        for row in rows[0:(len(rows)) - 2]:
            time.sleep(8)
            cells = row.find_all('td')
            cells = cells[0:9]  # drop the last column

            # store data in list
            single.append([cell.text for cell in cells])


def next_page(name, data):
    # check if any link to next page is available
    # iterate every page.
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.gridPager a')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    links_for_pages = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.gridPager a')
    for page in range(len(links_for_pages)):
        # new list, to by pass stale element exception
        links_for_pages_new = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.gridPager a')
        # do not click on link for new page slot
        if links_for_pages_new[page].text != '...':
            links_for_pages_new[page].click()
            # if this can be replaced with some other wait method to save the time
            time.sleep(8)
            extract_table_current(name, data)


def second_page_slot():
    # find specific link for going to page 11 and click.
    try:
        link_for_page_slot = driver.find_element_by_link_text('...')
        link_for_page_slot.click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False


# main code

page_data = []

time.sleep(5)
view = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
    '#ContentPlaceHolder1_ucRecordView_ddlPageSize'))
view.select_by_value('50')
driver.close()
for district in ALL_Districts:

    b = "06"
    c = "2020"
    district_directory = os.path.join(Download_Directory, f'{district}{b}{c}')
    if not os.path.exists(district_directory):
        os.mkdir(district_directory)
    for i in range(1, 30):
        # reoping the page to wipe out the catch.
        options = FirefoxOptions()
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        options.add_argument("--private-window")
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
        get_url(URL)
        # entering date and assuring that 01 to 09 is entered correctly
        if i < 10:
            i = f'{str("0")}{str(i)}'
        date_from = str(i) + b + c
        enter_date(date_from)
        # select district
        district_selection(district)
        time.sleep(3)
        # start the search
        search()
        time.sleep(7)
        if not number_of_records():
            continue
        extract_table_current(district, page_data)
        time.sleep(3)
        if not next_page(district, page_data):
            district_data = pd.DataFrame(page_data, columns=COLUMNS)
            district_data.to_csv(os.path.join(district_directory, f'{district}{i}{b}{c}.csv'))
            continue
        extract_table_current(district, page_data)
        district_data = pd.DataFrame(page_data, columns=COLUMNS)
        district_data.to_csv(os.path.join(district_directory, f'{district}{i}{b}{c}.csv'))
        driver.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Request is a very nice and simple, but powerful package. When you have learned it then you will be grateful :) You can use request to navigate around the page and sometimes even to login or send messages.

I don't know scrappy but I have been using BeautifulSoup alot and that one is fairly simple to learn as well, you just get the "soup" of data from requests and then you use BS to filter your data.

My recommendation for you is to start from scratch, just one step at a time.

Start by getting your page and then get your data little by little :)

```
page = requests.get('https://www.mhpolice.maharashtra.gov.in/Citizen/MH/PublishedFIRs.aspx')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
```

Comment: Tried and bumped here:
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.mhpolice.maharashtra.gov.in', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /Citizen/MH/PublishedFIRs.aspx (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError("hostname 'www.mhpolice.maharashtra.gov.in' doesn't match 'citizen.mahapolice.gov.in'"

Comment: It looks like they are monitoring how many requests an IP address is making to the server, and blocks you after a number of requests. probably you have to wait a bit before the blocking of your ip stops.

Comment: should I try using ways to evade the blocking like changing IP address etc? is any such option available?

Comment: Yes of course it is available, but I don't think it is necessary. Just try not to send 100 requests (too many) in less than 5 minutes :) 

If you need to use proxies there are alot avalible on the internet. But as I said I think that is out of the scope of what you need.

Comment: I just run the code, the simple one you gave, once I got this error!

Comment: @mama that is not the cause of the 'max retries' error. It's much more likely that the OP is accessing the website via a hostname that has a misconfigured certificate only covering the second hostname shown. Indeed, visiting the first hostname redirects to the second one. Try `citizen.mahapolice.gov.in` for your hostname instead.